# Is IDLE the correct platform to use for Python programming?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to Python and downloaded the 2.x version on my Mac (I'm not using 3.x because my University course only allows us to submit work using 2.x).

However, having downloaded I'm not sure where to type my code, it was much more simple with Mathematica and Maple which I learnt last term. Here is a screenshot of all of the results when I type Python into my applications:[image: Screenshot after a Python search in applications]

Then I click on the Python 2.7 option and this comes up:[image]

I click on IDLE and it comes up with a platform for typing code, which looks like this [image]

but I'm not sure if it's the correct one that I would be expected to submit work using. The reason for this is that it's called IDLE, whereas when I used Mathematica and Maple all I had to do was click on 'Mathematica' or 'Maple' and a platform would come up for typing code straight away.

Is IDLE the correct platform for typing code using Python?

Comment: Mathematica is software. Maple is software. Python is **not** software, Python is a programming language. IDLE is a software to write and edit Python source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not *the* correct one, it's just one of many possible ways to edit your .py files and work on Python projects. There are many other IDEs around, and some developers just use their favorite text editors with Python plugins

Unlike Mathematica, Maple and MATLAB, you're not really bound to any particular development environment

Comment: OK, so basically there are no problems with typing Python code using this specific IDLE?

One of the things that also had me concerned was that I can't delete the code once it's been done. This makes my work look messy if I make a mistake and can't erase it. Why is this?

Comment: No problems, should work, and I'm sure you'll find your favorite as you go!

Comment: @Olly Price You can't delete code in the Python _shell_. To create scripts that can be edited anytime, you go to `File > New Window` and type your script there. The shell is interactive and allows you to try out things quickly.

Comment: @Olly: It just that when IDLE starts it immediately launches a Python command shell. As TidB points out, it has separate features including an editor to handle the creation, modification, and running of Python scripts. If you get really desperate, look around for some documentation and/or tutorials and read them.